# pyspark can do anything but save the result because of out of heap error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This is the first time I have huge enough datasets that I can not use my regular tools anymore. So I am digging into Spark but I can't understand why I run out of heap to save a simple csv file.

I Have a pipeline like this which works fine:

```
spark.read\
    .format("parquet")\
    .load('/mnt/data/share/parquets/quotes-*.parquet')\
    .withColumn("symbol", SQL.regexp_extract('filename', r'\/([^\/]*).csv$', 1))\
    .withColumn("DDate", col("Date").cast(DateType()))\
    .select(["symbol", "DDate", "value"])\
    .filter(col("DDate") >= effective_date)\
    .groupBy("symbol").pivot("DDate").sum("value")\
    .count()

>>> 325073
```

But at the very moment I change the last line from `count()` to `.repartition(1).write.csv("/tmp/test.csv")` I get an out-of-heap error.

```
23/04/05 22:30:27 WARN RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
[148.576s][warning][gc,alloc] Executor task launch worker for task 12.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 662): Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 131074 words
23/04/05 22:30:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 12.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 662)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
23/04/05 22:30:27 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 662),5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
23/04/05 22:30:27 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner@4fefe566 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2558895b[Shutting down, pool size = 12, active threads = 12, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 656]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1355)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.launchTask(Executor.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.$anonfun$reviveOffers$1(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.$anonfun$reviveOffers$1$adapted(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.reviveOffers(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

What I don't understand, a csv file should be able to be written line by line and I doubt that the lines so big. I use the following settings:

```
spark.driver.memory              4g
spark.executor.memory            12g
```

Also increasing or decreasing the number of partitions (or even omitting the `repartition(..)` does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, verify is there any data spill is happening in any of stage. If yes, try to increase the shuffle partitions or increase executor memory. After applying both still issue persists then it is dataskew issue you are facing. Try to solve the dataskew issue using various techniques like salt, broadcast etc.